# scaling from rectangle to square

Tags: android, graphics

I newbie to android and graphic development.
I implement a custom-view and want to draw to canvas.
I set the customview size to be (width x (width/2)) so the rectangle height is half of the width.
Now when start drawing, its easy for me to draw on a square area like 1X1.
like this:

```
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int ChosenSize = Math.min(widthSize, heightSize);
    int width = ChosenSize;
    int height = (int)(ChosenSize/2);   
    setMeasuredDimension(width,height);
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    float width = (float)getWidth();
    float height = (float)getHeight();
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(width ,height );

    // start drawing in a 1X1 square coordinates

    canvas.restore();

}
```

But after restore() the result is stretched a little bit.
What am i doing wrong ??
Note: I have notice that when not using scale and working with the rectangle width and height the 
result looks Ok

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

The reason my drawing stretch, is because I scale from rectangle to square which is mistake.

Usually when canvas is square it easy to draw on 1x1 square, so I scale to canvas.scale(width,height),
But when canvas is rectangle like (width,width/2), I should scale to (width,height/width) to get rect of 1x2.

so after I change scaling to canvas.scale(width,height/width)